# How to ng-repeat different objects from JSON file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

sry guys i have edited my question. hopefully you guys can understand now :D
what i was trying to say is i have file named data.json and inside that file i have these data's:

```
{
"FOOD": [{
     "item_name": "Starter"
}],
"DRINKS": [{
     "item_name": "COKE"
}]
}
```

i have written codes in app.js

```
app.controller('DataCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$http', 
     function($scope, $state, $http) {$http.get('js/data.json').success ( function(data) {
    $scope.FOOD = data.FOOD;
    $scope.DRINKS = data.DRINKS;
})
```

}]);

details.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Menus">
  <ion-content ng-controller="DataCtrl">
    <ion-item ng-repeat="i in FOOD" class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap item-icon-right">
       <h2 class="title">{{i.item_name}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

i can pull all the data from food but what i want is i want to dynamically change the data between FOOD n DRINKS.when someone clicks on the food it should show FOOD data and when someone clicks on DRINKS i want `ng-repeat="i in FOOD"` should change to `ng-repeat="i in DRINKS"`. how can i achieve this?

Comment: Please try to write your question so that it is clearer exactly what you are trying to achieve. Also, include code you have tried.

Comment: And generally speaking avoiding slang such as 'plz' will make people more inclined to help you. Don't want to put a newcomer off but you have to make the effort to word your question in a decent manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt understand your question completely.May be this code will help you.

when someone clicks on the FOOD(parameter='FOOD'), `$scope.array` is populated by using FOOD data and when someone clicks on DRINKS(parameter='DRINKS'),`$scope.array` is populated by using DRINKS data.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.parameter = "DRINKS";
    $scope.data = {
        "FOOD": [{
            "item_name": "Starter"
        }],
        "DRINKS": [{
            "item_name": "COKE"
        }]
    }
    $scope.FOOD = $scope.data.FOOD;
    $scope.DRINKS = $scope.data.DRINKS;
    if ($scope.parameter == 'FOOD') $scope.array = $scope.FOOD;
    else $scope.array = $scope.DRINKS;
});
```

**template**

```
<ion-view view-title="Menus">
  <ion-content ng-controller="DataCtrl">
    <ion-item ng-repeat="i in array" class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap item-icon-right">
       <h2 class="title">{{i.item_name}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Stack Overflow Demo**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.parameter = "DRINKS";
  $scope.data = {
    "FOOD": [{
      "item_name": "Starter"
    }],
    "DRINKS": [{
      "item_name": "COKE"
    }]
  }
  $scope.FOOD = $scope.data.FOOD;
  $scope.DRINKS = $scope.data.DRINKS;
  if ($scope.parameter == 'FOOD') $scope.array = $scope.FOOD;
  else $scope.array = $scope.DRINKS;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="i in array">
    {{i.item_name}}
  </div>

</div>
<script>
</script>
```

Comment: Mushin, i have modified my question i guess now is more understandable.

Comment: @Zscorp:Glad to help you